# Angular reactive formgroup clear error in component not clearing from template

Tags: angular7

I am dynamically clearing the errors of my reactive form like:

```
this.courseForm.setErrors(null);
```

But the errors are still displayed in my template:

```
<form [formGroup]="courseForm" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="alert-group" *ngIf="submitted && formGroup.errors?.coursedates">
      <div *ngFor="let err of formGroup.errors?.coursedates?.value" role="alert" class="error">
        {{err}}
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to clear formgroup errors in template as well?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Errors for each control doesn't populate for formgroup errors. So clearing formgroup errors doesn't remove the errors from each of its form-controls.

We need to setErrors(null) for each control inside formgroup. Here is how we do it.

```
Object.keys(this.courseForm.controls).forEach(key => {
  this.form.get(key).setErrors(null);
});
```

Make sure to mark it as answer if the solution fixes your issue.